# Convergence in $L_p$ and a.s. but with different limits possible?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let the r.v. $X_n\rightarrow^{L_p}X$ and $X_n\rightarrow^{a.s.}Y$. Can we say that $Y=^{a.s.}X$, or $Y=X$? Why?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes, because the convergence in $L^p$ implies the convergence a.s. up to passing to some subsequence.
Thus we would get
$$
X_{n_k}\stackrel{a.s.}{\to} X
$$
but
$$
X_n\stackrel{a.s.}{\to} Y
$$
implies that
$$
X_{n_k}\stackrel{a.s.}{\to} Y
$$

thus
$$
X=Y
$$
 a.s.

Answer (score 3):

Almost sure convergence implies convergence in probability. Convergence in the $p$-th mean implies convergence in probability too. If the sequence converges in probability, its limit is almost surely unique. Hence, $X=Y$ a.s.